# html_content not working for ui component

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent

The Ui components the following tag works, but only onces. If i tried to use another htmlcontent tag then the new tag does not appear.

```
<htmlContent name="html_content">
    <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Orders\Additional</argument>
</htmlContent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you use same name for two content block. Try following way:

```
<htmlContent name="html_content">
    <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Orders\Additional</argument>
</htmlContent>
<htmlContent name="html_content_another">
    <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Orders\Additional</argument>
</htmlContent>
```

Comment: I had solved the problem. But forgot to update here. Thank you.